# Quick Deployment Job failing when no item in Quick deploy item list

Tags: sharepoint

I have a content deployment job from one server to another....content deployment job works fine but when I turn on Quick Deploy job it start showing me system event error...

I later figured it out that quick deploy is working fine if there is atleast one item in quick deploy items list otherwise its giving me error.

In quick deploy settings I put it as after every 30 minutes so I am getting error after every 30 minutes in system event....

```
The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Administration.ContentDeploymentJobhe Execute method of job definition Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Administration.ContentDeploymentJobDefinition (ID daa20dd3-f6ad-4e27-923a-1ebf26c71723) threw an exception. More information is included below.

ContentDeploymentJobReport with ID '{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}' was not found.
Parameter name: jobReportId
```

and

```
Publishing: Content deployment job failed. Error: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: ContentDeploymentJobReport with ID '{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}' was not found.
Parameter name: jobReportId
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Administration.ContentDeploymentJobReport.GetInstance(Guid jobReportId)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Administration.ContentDeploymentJob.get_LastReport()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Administration.ContentDeploymentJob.get_SQMDeploymentJobFlags()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Administration.ContentDeploymentJob.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that if we have any item in our authoring environment which needs to get to Production in quick deployment list...we are not getting this error...so i just find the workaround for now by deploying any page after setting up my content deployment jobs...that way I am not getting this issue....